# Combine IF and VLOOKUP for blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I've read a few different questions can't figure out how to get them to work with my formula.

I'm using a simple Vlookup to look up a price field on sheet 2 and bring back the absolute value.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$1:$1048576,6,FALSE)
```

I am thinking about changing this to use index match as Vlookup doesn't look left and sometimes breaks.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$F:$F,MATCH('Amazon and Ebay '!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

I want a formula  to be able to read field 6 within sheet 2 if it's blank bring back a value from 5.

I understand using,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"FOUND","NOT FOUND")
```

Would tell me if the field is blank or not.

Would can I get it to if "Not Found" bring the field back from column 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sup>I want a formula to be able to read field 6 within sheet 2 if it's blank bring back a value from 5.
> Would can I get it to if "Not Found" bring the field back from column 5?</sup>

The [ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) function can determine if the return is blank and pass along processing to a second (largely) duplicate formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(Sheet2!$F:$F, MATCH('Amazon and Ebay '!A2, Sheet2!A:A, 0))), 
            INDEX(Sheet2!$E:$E, MATCH('Amazon and Ebay '!A2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)),
            INDEX(Sheet2!$F:$F, MATCH('Amazon and Ebay '!A2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)))
```

You might want to wrap the whole thing in an [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) in case there is no match to begin with.

<sub>Is there supposed to be a space at the end of the 'Amazon and Ebay ' worksheet's name?</sub>

Comment: That worked brilliantly, thank you for noticing the space at the end of the Sheet. That could have caused issues.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `Index` function within the `True` part of the `If` statement. Also, rather than `ISNUMBER`, I would use `ISERROR` (because `ISNUMBER` may return true in cases where a match can't be found):

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))),INDEX(Sheet2!$F:$F,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"NOT FOUND")
```

In plain English, this is doing:

> If the `Match` function does **not** return an error, return the result of the `Match` function, else, return `"Not Found"`.